# how to remove a TR which have a TD that contain specific text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following markup which have `SPAN >> Table >> TR >> TD`:-

[image]

now i want to specify either using css or jquery to remove the TR which have a TD that contain the word "Question" inside `<nobr>` tag. so can anyone adivce how i can do so ? thanks

Comment: by using .formtable>tr:nth-child(3) {display:none;}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to compare the *exact* text of the `<nobr>` element, then remove the closest `<tr>`

```js
$("span table tr td nobr").filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() === "Question";
}).closest("tr").remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h3>
          <nobr>Question</nobr>
        </h3>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Untouched
      </td>
    </tr>
    
  </table>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `:has()` selector along with `:contains()` selecor to achieve what you want,

```
$("tr:has(td nobr:contains('Question'))").remove();
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0obxtkkb/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with jQuery as shown below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('td').each(function(){
        if($(this).find('nobr').text() === 'Question') {
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It would have been helpful if you could provide HTML. I would have created fiddle but You can try below solution

Iterate tr in table and find the tr having

```
   $("table.ms-formtable > tbody > tr").each(function(){
       var text = $(this).find("td:first").find("nobr").text();
       if(text === 'Question') {
          $(this).remove();
       }
   });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9tw2kfek/